# How do I use bootstrap-formhelpers data-format in a @Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, formatting

If you take a look at [this bootstrap documentation](http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/phone.html) for formhelpers, I can use

```
<input type="text" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-format="+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd" placeholder="Cell or Home Phone" required>
```

to format a textbox when a user enters a phone number. I want to use an `@Html.TextBoxFor` or an `@Html.EditorFor` to do the same thing. How do I accomplish this in mvc? Here is what I have tried:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control bfh-phone" data-format="+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd" value="@Model.PhoneNumber" placeholder="Cell or Home Phone" required>
```

and

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control bfh-phone", @placeholder = "Cell or Home Phone", @data-format="+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd" } })
```

both of which gives a `object reference` razor syntax error. How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the overload of `EditorFor()` that accepts `object` to add html attributes, you need to use an `_` (underscore) character which will be translated to a `-` (hyphen) by the razor engine. Use `data_format = ".."`, not `data-format = ".."`

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = 
    new { @class = "..", placeholder = "..", data_format="+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd" } })
```

Note also you do not need the leading `@` character for `placeholder` or `data_format` (its only required for reserved words).